# System.arraycopy inside a for loop isn't switching matrix rows?

Tags: java, arrays

```
System.out.println("Before decryption:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(output));
    int top, bottom;
    bottom = this.size-1;
    for(top = 0; top<bottom; top++,bottom--){
        char[] topMatrix = output[top];
        char[] bottomMatrix = output[bottom];
        System.out.println(top+" "+bottom);
        System.arraycopy(topMatrix, 0, output[bottom], 0, size);
        System.arraycopy(bottomMatrix, 0, output[top], 0, size);
    }
    System.out.println("After Decryption: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(output));
}
```

Above is the code I am using to switch the first and last rows, then second and second to last rows and so on until it runs out rows to switch in a 2d array.

Here is the output:

```
Input: abcdefghi
Before decryption:
[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
0 2
After Decryption: 
[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [a, b, c]]
```

So what seems to be happening here is that the arraycopy does copy the first row to the last row, but somehow the bottomMatrix variable seems to be updated to (abc) instead of its original (ghi).

What gives? It seems like its executing the first arraycopy then exiting the loop and coming back, instead of executing all the statements in the loop.

Comment: just thinking about making my own method for arraycopy to see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying code to the same array, so when your top writes to bottom, it is overwriting bottom, and then the same thing is getting written to top. You copy abc over ghi and then try to copy abc to abc.

You should use different arrays for input and output to avoid this issue.

```
System.out.println("Before decryption:");
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(output));
int top, bottom;
bottom = this.size-1;
char[][] copy = new char[size][size];
for(top = 0; top<=bottom; top++,bottom--){
    char[] topMatrix = output[top];
    char[] bottomMatrix = output[bottom];
    System.out.println(top+" "+bottom);
    System.arraycopy(topMatrix, 0, copy[bottom], 0, size);
    System.arraycopy(bottomMatrix, 0, copy[top], 0, size);
}
System.out.println("After Decryption: ");
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(copy));
```

Also note that I have changed to <= instead of <, because you are writing to a new array so in case of odd sized arrays it will not copy the center row if you use only <. For even sized arrays, the same condition will work because top>bottom after half is processed.

Comment: wow, fast, I just dumped arraycopy and went with array.clone which worked out. But I like your solution, it is inclusive and uses the system tools. Thank you so much!

Comment: Small edit, at the end you should print copy instead of output, already updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Arrays, like all objects in Java, are like pointers in C.
So `char[] bottomMatrix = output[bottom];` does not copy the array, `bottomMatrix` now just refers to the same memory address as `output[bottom]`.

But if I'm not mistaken, you don't even have to copy, you can just reassign:

```
for(top = 0; top<bottom; top++,bottom--){
    char[] intermediate = output[top];
    output[top] = output[bottom];
    output[bottom] = intermediate;
}
```

Comment: very true, i could have also used System.arraycopy instead of using the expression notation to avoid the usage of the pointers. Thank you for your clear explanation! I just learned C not too long ago, so it definitely makes sense.